# Autocompletion not working when Intersecting with Generic Param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code ([playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneWgG2gbgF44BvOFAFxwAjABo4AIyFi4AX34dajGFSowAnmCRwACjjAMAPDrhIAHjCR0AJh2S0o1w0yjA6Ac3Eo66gHxdeWXEAFVMLK1s4AAlggFkAGQBRFiQQK3huGISAEWAAN2TU9P9uPjQAVyZcPQgwIQBrJHUITDgNLRa4VnY4AB84AAMAEh4XN3dZMDMBuTgAMkRiGAA6LPiAQRgYVwlyyyNg3yo4E-ndOAB6C7hDAFp7h8e2qHU2iC7cNLp4GAALYA4YBQsH4NjgdAgMGAaG0KD2EFo4BSUPocEw0DgsXUACEIGZVJR2tpcWZkDBylA6AFjGFLDY7EgHE4xh4vD4SoEQrSIhw1oUvhlonF4rkCikBb4ABTHU5gfQMIQ1AzGEJHSgASi4-gAUgBlAAay356QJSiYcBJAWQ6BW6KgAHdgdZkJhJZhynQMMBUSTpZRTnA5bUGKIZSciJgqJq+ERyZTweUWCw5JqUBwSWSKXRTfRzVjLdxJZrOP5DJaKlUQErOAAiFASGuXfxXcHvOEwd6IsDIpDiXbwYDwAD6AKHbU02gYKEw2hzykxOLxACYAkWtTcSYYeLJ-BWO1X9LWUI2Ls3rn8AXB7dB6iHW1CYW1ftp3FYkK40HO84uzABmVdAlAKAgAqujyluaIQBAQgsu4ci+MWpaWjwyyoYBwEMPI6IQLWEjAieZ5Xr8ryXgM2G4fhMwoEmED2kg1hEVYcDAHA1jANY3yse8ZZ4lu2Ewds4zyKeVBAA))

```
import React from 'react';

const colors = { a: 1, b: 1, } as const

type Props<P extends Record<string, any> = {}, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLDivElement> = { customProp: keyof typeof colors | `${string}px` } & React.HTMLAttributes<T>
    & P // <---------- try to comment this part and notice autocompletion for MyBox

type BoxReturn = <P extends Record<string, any> = {}, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLDivElement>(
    props: Props<P, T>
) => JSX.Element

const Box = React.forwardRef(function Box(
    props,
    ref
) { return null }) as BoxReturn

const MyBox = () => <Box customProp="ab" /> // no auto complete, but it _is_ type safe 

const MyBox2 = () => <Box<{}> customProp="a" /> // this works, notice the generic

const MyBox3 = (params: Props<{ foo: string }>) => <Box {...params} foo="bar" /> // why is `foo="bar"` allowed when i didnt do <Box<{foo: string} />
```

The Autocompletion(ctrl + space) doesn't work with VScode for `MyBox` while it does for `MyBox2`. If you comment `& P` then Autocompletion will work for `MyBox` as well.

#### Questions

- When doing just `<Box />` the default value for `P` should be `{}` so why do i have to specify it in `MyBox2`?
- If i do `const MyBox3 = (params: Props<{ foo: string }>) => <Box {...params} foo="bar" />` why does the generic param's type become `{foo: string}`?
- For `MyBox` why is `customProp`'s type `never`?

Thank you so much

Comment: It's just how TypeScript infers generics when you don't provide them. Generics don't necessarily dictate the parameter's type. That would make APIs that utilize the feature that generics are inferred from parameter types impossible. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwCEcAPAHgBV4RiMRVgBneAbwF8A+ACgAdYoBbELRgAueOQCUY8gG4AsAChFRYpzYTlJUsyQ4cYhhhhZUAc3gc1rCTPgB6O-FQ5sYBAAscAd3hZ47qAA3BAwceGQGBAADRD0ozTI2Lh1Y-XgAInSLG3tHFL0DIxNzVngoBgYsU1QoACMIELC2BLVdNMzs2wcy5FD+KFcoCAgAT19URBAYOGAypny0w2MzCzAE7TbC5ZLkzYys6y7HCDxzKHp4YJhanEj4EU4gA)

Comment: I didn't understand that, could you please explain more 

When doing just `<Box />` isnt the generic `{}` and if i replace ` & P` in `Props` with just `& {}` it works. 

